# Installing srvany.exe to run a jar file as a service using InstallShield (without editing the registry)

Tags: windows-services, installshield

We are trying to install a Java program to run as a windows service. Of the various available options(JSW, YAJSW, Launch4J, procrun, WinRun4J etc etc), we would like to use srvany.exe and install it using InstallShield. The Windows documentation says ...

> Using RegEdit : create a "Parameters" key for your service (e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MyService\Paramaters\` )
>   Using RegEdit : within the newly created "Parameters" key , create a string value called `Application` and enter the full path to the application you are wanting to run as a service.

Is there a way to achieve this using InstallShield without using InstallShield's registry editor? Is there an InstallScript call that can take care of adding and removing "Parameters" to the srvany entry in the registry? The solution should to work for Windows 2008R2 & 2003R2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we were not able to find a favourable solution within available time, we decided to not use the srvany.exe. We decided to use YAJSW and within InstallShield use "Text File Changes" to modify the wrapper.conf for the YAJSW to launch our java application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Basic MSI project type,  I find a combination of the ServiceInstall, ServiceControl and Registry tables to be a good solution.   Due to the fact that ServAny is really just a thunking layer, the ServiceInstall table can't fully describe the service without a little assistance from the Registry table.  Still, no custom actions should be needed and the MSI will be very solid and robust.

Comment: thank you, we do not want to directly operate with Registry tables.